# Question about definition of some classes of bimodules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, notation, modules, definition

Suppose that we have a ring $R$ and a $R$-$R$ bimodule $M$ such that:

For every $r\in R$ and $m\in M$ there exists $r'\in R$ such that $m\cdot r=r'\bullet m.$

Examples of this bimodules can be seen as follows.

If $R$ is a commutative ring, $M$ is a central $R$-$R$ bimodule (that is $mr=rm,$ for all $m\in M,r\in R$) and $G$ is a group acting on $R$ by automorphisms. Then, for any $g\in G$ we can construct a new $R$-$R$-bimodule $_gM_I,$ where .

$_gM_I=M$ as sets and the operations of $R$ on $M$ are $r\cdot m=g(r)m$ and $m\bullet r=mr.$ Then we see that $r\cdot m=g(r)m=mg(r)=m\bullet g(r), $ that is, $$r\cdot m=m\bullet g(r).$$

I want to know if there is a name for this kind of bimodules.

Thanks.

Comment: For the example: If $R$ is an associative ring and $g:R \to R^{op}$ is an isomorphism, then $r \cdot m = m \bullet g(r)$ works nicely. This is used for group rings $R=kG$ with $g(x)=x$ for $x \in k$ and $g(y) = y^{-1}$ for $y \in G$. $R$ like the group ring are called rings with involution and are pretty well studied. If $g$ does not have order 2, I suspect they are less studied since you don't get as nice of left-right symmetry.

Comment: Nice example, just one question. What do you mean by $G.R$?

Comment: Replace “$G. R$ like” with “$G$. Rings $R$ like”

Comment: Ok thanks. Well maybe there is no standard name.